# Cannot update to Magento2.1.0 from Magento2.0.7

Tags: upgrade, magento2

I installed magento2.0.7 through web setup interface. Now I am trying to upgrade this to Magento 2.1.0 using composer. But the issue is, composer identifying wrong php version and hence upgradation is halted.
I have applied the patch MVD 532

Error is

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.0.7, required as 2.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.0.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/module-bundle-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-bundle-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package magento/module-theme-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-theme-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package magento/module-widget-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-widget-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-catalog-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package magento/module-customer-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-customer-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 7
    - The requested package magento/module-cms-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-cms-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 8
    - The requested package magento/module-tax-sample-data (locked at 100.0.5, required as 100.1.0) is satisfiable by magento/module-tax-sample-data[100.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got this resolved by updating my composer.json. To upgrade to 2.1.x from 2.0.x,

1. Edit composer.json, especially these

`"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.x",
}`

and

```
    "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/sample-data-media": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*",
```

M2.1.x needs components as 100.1 instead of 100.0

Now rest part same as we do earlier

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This would work efficiently as worked for me. Enjoy Upgrading :)